# Cpp Instance in Instance in... existance

Tags: c++, oop, embedded

I have some classes in hierarchy. So let's call first class Hardware, it recieves and sends data and each Instance of it wll have some unique parameters. Let it be:

```
class Hardware{
  private:
    SPI_TypeDef** Instance; 
    GPIO_Port* Port;
    GPIO_Pin Pin;
    int Settings;
  public
    Hardware();
    Hardware(GPIO_Port* Port, GPIO_Pin Pin, SPI_HandleTypeDef* SPIx);
    void TXRX_Data(Byte* TxBuf, Byte* RxBuf, int Length);
};
```

Then I have class, that controls external device,each device has its own CS (as it is SPI):

```
class Device{
    private: 
       Hardware Sender;
       Byte Parameter_Buffer;
    public: 
       Device();
       Device(GPIO_Port* Port, GPIO_Pin Pin, SPI_HandleTypeDef* SPIx);
       void SendParameter(Byte Param);
       Byte GetParameter();
};
```

It's constructor is just

```
Device::Device(GPIO_Port* Port, GPIO_Pin Pin, SPI_HandleTypeDef* SPIx){
   this->Sender = Hardware(GPIO_Port* Port, GPIO_Pin Pin, SPI_HandleTypeDef* SPIx);
}
```

And after that all I have the main control class

```
class DeviceArray{
private:
   Device Devices[DEVICE_QUANTITY];
   Byte Parameters_Buff[DEVICE_QUANTITY];
public:
   DeviceArray();
   DeviceArray(GPIO_Port** Ports, GPIO_Pin* Pins, SPI_HandleTypeDef* SPIx);
   void SendParameters(Byte* Params);
   Byte* GetParameters();
}
```

It's constructor is:

```
DeviceArray::DeviceArray(GPIO_Port** Ports, GPIO_Pin* Pins, SPI_HandleTypeDef* SPIx){
    for(uint8_t i = 0;i < DEVICE_QUANTITY; i++){
         this->Devices[i] = Device(Ports[i], Pins[i],SPIx);
    }  
}
```

I'll have only one object of this class in my program and it will be global.

And I wonder if instances of Device and their parameters will not be deleted after DeviceArray constructor is closed. And the same is for Hardware (Sender) instances.

The given code is quite abstract, but it is very similar to program I'm trying to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I wonder if instances of Device and their parameters will not be deleted after DeviceArray constructor is closed. And the same is for Hardware (Sender) instances.

Yes, instances of the two types will be destroyed, but that doesn't matter.

For example the line

```
this->Devices[i] = Device(Ports[i], Pins[i],SPIx);
```

creates a temporary `Device` object which will be destroyed at the end of the statement, but that doesn't matter because before that `=` will call the implicit move assignment operator of `Device` which will move the members of the temporary `Device` object into the `this->Devices[i]` object.

Comment: And the same is for Hardware. But will it keep it this way: temporary Hardware copies to temporary Sender in temporary Device that also cpoies in DeviceArrayInstance->Devices[i] and the last one will not be destroyed after DeviceArray constructor is closed? That is what I am worried about

Comment: @lazba All of the temporary ones will be destroyed. At the end only `Devices` with all its subobjects is left. But e.g. `Devices[0].Sender.Instance` will have the pointer value that `Hardware`'s constructor set it to in the temporary.